# How to add a part of a list to a function?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, matrix

I want to be able to add a specific portion of a list to a part of a function but this fucntion intakes 6 variables where as the list is of example:

```
{x,y,z},{x,y,z},{x,y,z}...
```

and the fucntion is like:

```
Fucntion[x_,y_,z_,a_,b_,c_] :=...
```

How do I add only the x,y,z of each list to the x,y,z of the function? Apply seems likes the best option, can this even be done?

Comment: It isn't clear what you want, but I guess that the answer  when you have e.g. `list = {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}, {x3, y3, z3}};` is `f[#1, #2, #3, a, b, c] & @@@ list` or simply `f[##, a, b, c] & @@@ list`.

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, x, y, z, list, func];
list = {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}, {x3, y3, z3}};

func[x_, y_, z_, a_, b_, c_] := {a, b, c}.{x, y, z}

func[##, a, b, c] & @@ list[[1]]
(* a x1+b y1+c z1 *)
func[## & @@ #, a, b, c] &@list[[1]]
(* a x1+b y1+c z1 *)

func[##, a, b, c] & @@@ list
(* {a x1+b y1+c z1,a x2+b y2+c z2,a x3+b y3+c z3} *)
func[## & @@ #, a, b, c] & /@ list
(* {a x1+b y1+c z1,a x2+b y2+c z2,a x3+b y3+c z3} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}, {x3, y3, z3}};
Fucntion[x_, y_, z_, a_, b_, c_] := {a, b, c}.{x, y, z}
Fucntion[Sequence @@ #, a, b, c] & /@ list

(*{a x1 + b y1 + c z1, a x2 + b y2 + c z2, a x3 + b y3 + c z3}*)
```